# If $abc(a+b+c)=3$, prove that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq 8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If $abc(a+b+c)=3$, prove that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)\geq 8$

My work. 
$$abc(a+b+c)=3$$
$$a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2=3$$
Adding $5$ to both sides 
$$a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2+5=5+3$$
$$a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2+5=8$$
.
. 
...
.

Comment: are the variables assumed to be positive?

Comment: @Dr.Sonnhard Graubner, I don't know. That's not stated in the question.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I think so. Consider $a=b=-1,c=3$.